# How do I capture multiple lines between to hashtags using Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse this markdown file. I would like to capture the sections between the headings. What's wrong with my regex?! I'm having trouble capture multiple lines of content.

Here is the regex I wrote.

```
# (.*)\n\nURL: \[(.*)\]\((.*)\)\n\n(\[THIS IS A CHOICE NO CONTENT REQUIRED\]|(.*))#
```

```
# English

URL: [https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/en](https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/en)

[THIS IS A CHOICE NO CONTENT REQUIRED]


#### What is a suspension?

URL: [https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/#/en/education/suspensions/suspension](https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/#/en/education/suspensions/suspension)

A suspension means students are removed from school temporarily for a specific period of time. Students may be suspended for a period of time ranging from one school day up to 20 school days. Students cannot go to school or take part in regular school activities or events while on suspension.

Sources:

* [http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/safeschools/suspexp.html](http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/safeschools/suspexp.html)

#### What does a principal consider when suspending students?

URL: [https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/#/en/education/suspensions/suspension-consideration](https://legal-clinic.mfso.ca/#/en/education/suspensions/suspension-consideration)

Students cannot go to school or take part in regular school activities or events while on suspension. Of the activities listed below:

* Uttering a threat to inflict serious bodily harm on another person
* being under the influence of alcohol or cannabis (unless the student is authorized to use cannabis for medical purposes)
* possessing alcohol, cannabis (unless the student is authorized to use cannabis for medical purposes), or illegal drugs
* swearing at a teacher or at any person in a position of authority
* committing an act of vandalism that causes extensive damage to school property at the student's school or to property on school premises
* bullying, including cyber-bullying
* any other activities identified in school board policy.

Suspension will be considered whether the activity took place at school, at a school-related activity (e.g., a field trip), or in any other circumstances where the student's behaviour has an impact on the school climate (like cyber-bullying).

Sources:

* [http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/safeschools/suspexp.html](http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/safeschools/suspexp.html)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Right now it looks like this https://regex101.com/r/PEfxhK/1

Comment: what scripting language?

Comment: I'm using Node, but I'll use pyhton if need be.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, but it's only capturing the first line, not the subsequent lines.

Comment: @AbdulAmoud Do you mean like this? `^#+ *(.+)\n\nURL: \[([^][]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)((?:\r?\n(?!#).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/8xh6zY/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, one option could be omitting the alternation `|` as the second alternative would match a single line.

Then you could use a repeating pattern inside a capture group to match all lines that do not start with `#`

Note that this is for the example data, for advanced parsing of a markdown file you could look into a parser.

```
^#+ *(\S.*)\r?\n\r?\nURL: \[([^][]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)((?:\r?\n(?!#).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `#+ *` Match 1+ times `#`, optional spaces
- `(\S.*)` Capture **group 1**, match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `\r?\n\r?\n` Match 2 newlines
- `URL:`  Match literally
- `\[([^][]+)\]` Capture in **group 2** all between `[` and `]`
- `\(([^()]+)\)` Capture in **group 3** all between `(` and `)`
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `(?:\r?\n(?!#).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with with a `#`
- `)` Close group 4

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3kSYv/1)

Comment: your regex is great, but could be he's in need of "text slurp" to go over multiple lines - if his regex only tackles 1 line at a time (as most regexps do), he'll never manage to use it.

Comment: @user2141046 I must say that I do not understand you comment. The OP uses newlines to match the next line, so there can be multiple lines matched. This pattern matches multiple lines in a repeating group as long as the assertion is true.

Comment: forth bird if his problem is caused by his OS giving the regex a single line each time, he will have no matches. If that's his source of his problem, your regexp (which is great, btw, but takes control over multiple lines) won't help him...

Comment: @user2141046 Lets wait for feedback of the OP.

Comment: This only works for PCRE. Not for Node ;(. I suspect this issue is due to group 4.

Comment: @AbdulAmoud It will also work for Node, see https://regex101.com/r/vBKC3b/1 I have escaped the `\]` in the character class.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thats it !

Comment: We just needed the /gm flag to capture multilines